# How to disable JMeter log information output to console (in java)

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin, jdk1.7

I was developing a jmeter test plan from java code, and I've installed jmeter api from maven.

It runs successfully. However, it shows lots of needless information on the console.

Here is my environment:

- JavaSE 1.7
- JMeter 3.0
- Windows 7

And I'm forced to do that although I know it's the old version of java and jmeter.

I've tried to configure jmeter.properties, logkit.xml and log4j.conf file, but it remains the same.

The information showing on console looks like:

```
WARN    2019-07-19 17:35:43.944 [jmeter.u] (): Exception 'null' occurred when fetching boolean property:'summariser.log', defaulting to:true
WARN    2019-07-19 17:35:43.944 [jmeter.u] (): Exception 'null' occurred when fetching boolean property:'summariser.out', defaulting to:true
INFO    2019-07-19 17:35:43.955 [jmeter.u] (): Setting Locale to zh_TW
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.457 [jmeter.g] (): setting element to enabled: true
INFO    2019-07-19 17:35:44.598 [jmeter.s] (): Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
INFO    2019-07-19 17:35:44.726 [jmeter.s] (): Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
INFO    2019-07-19 17:35:44.736 [jmeter.s] (): Using SaveService properties version 2.9
INFO    2019-07-19 17:35:44.736 [jmeter.s] (): All converter versions present and correct
Test Start
INFO    2019-07-19 17:35:44.739 [jmeter.e] (): Running the test!
INFO    2019-07-19 17:35:44.743 [jmeter.s] (): List of sample_variables: []
INFO    2019-07-19 17:35:44.743 [jmeter.s] (): List of sample_variables: []
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.750 [jorphan.] (): searchPathsOrJars : [SOMEWHERE\apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/ext]
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.750 [jorphan.] (): superclass : [interface org.apache.jmeter.functions.Function]
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.750 [jorphan.] (): innerClasses : true annotations: false
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.750 [jorphan.] (): contains: null notContains: null
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.750 [jorphan.] (): searchPathsOrJars : [SOMEWHERE\apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/ext]
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.754 [jorphan.] (): strPathsOrJars[0] : ApacheJMeter_tcp.jar
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.754 [jorphan.] (): strPathsOrJars[1] : SOMEWHERE/apache-jmeter-3.0/lib/ext
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.754 [jorphan.] (): strPathsOrJars[2] : ApacheJMeter_ftp.jar
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.754 [jorphan.] (): strPathsOrJars[3] : ApacheJMeter_junit.jar
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.754 [jorphan.] (): strPathsOrJars[4] : ApacheJMeter_java.jar
DEBUG   2019-07-19 17:35:44.754 [jorphan.] (): strPathsOrJars[5] : ApacheJMeter_mail.jar
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you are using the Maven plugin of JMeter, have you tried configuring the pom.xml as explained here: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Log-Levels

Comment: I'm also guessing that you are using version 2.0.0 if you are using JDK 1.7.  I would suggest updating to JDK 1.8 and using version 2.9.0 (latest version at the time of writing this)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suppress JMeter logging you can set the log level for JMeter to `FATAL_ERROR` by providing the relevant [JMeter Properties](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#2)

```
<configuration>
    <propertiesJMeter>
        <log_level.jmeter>FATAL_ERROR</log_level.jmeter>
        <log_level.jmeter.junit>FATAL_ERROR</log_level.jmeter.junit>
        <log_level.jorphan>FATAL_ERROR</log_level.jorphan>
    </propertiesJMeter>
</configuration>
```

In general you should not see any of JMeter log entries in the console so it seems you have configuration overrides somewhere so it would be better to revert the changes you made rather than applying my solution.

More information: [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)